# Can authentication with a relay be disabled for a specific address in smtp_sasl_password_maps?

Tags: postfix, sasl

Some email hosters are jerks. No matter your blacklist standing, SPK, DKIM, or DMARC, they will block your emails.

To deal with that, I've set up a relay using `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps`.
There are multiple domains with different usernames/passwords at our relay.
For instance, these are two domains on `smtp_sasl_password_maps`:

```
@example.com user1/pass1
@example.net user2/pass2
```

Now, because I want to work with those jerk email hosts to resolve the issue, I added my own email to `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps` like this:

```
me@example.com DUNNO
example.com relay
example.net relay
```

In general, this works BUT when I send an email using `me@example.com`, postfix tries to authenticate with the server that is not the relay using user1/pass1.

The documentation says:

> If no username:password entry is found, then the Postfix SMTP client will not attempt to authenticate to the remote host.

Is there any way to disable authentication otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is correct, but your problem is that the `@example.com` is a match for `me@example.com`. I think you cannot simply add a line with empty username and password, because the lookup tables are expected to be key-value pairs with non-empty values – even when the table is essentially a [list](https://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#lists).

> With some tables, however, Postfix needs to know only if the lookup key exists. Any non-empty lookup result value may be used here: the lookup result is not used.

However, the `hash:` is not the only [Postfix lookup table type](https://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types). What you want can be achieved using `regexp:` type lookup tables, instead:

`smtp_sasl_password_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/smtp_sasl_password_maps`

Then use *regular expressions* in the file as documented in [`REGEXP_TABLE(5)`](https://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html):

```
if !/^me@example\.com$/
/@example\.com$/ user1:pass1
endif

/@example\.net$/ user2:pass2
```

Finally, test with `postmap -q`:

```
$ /usr/sbin/postmap -q "user@example.com" regexp:./smtp_sasl_password_maps 
user1:pass1
$ /usr/sbin/postmap -q "user@example.net" regexp:./smtp_sasl_password_maps 
user2:pass2
$ /usr/sbin/postmap -q "me@example.com" regexp:./smtp_sasl_password_maps
$
```

Comment: Very cool! I didn't know about about `postmap` command and using the `regexp` table type for its conditional statement is a brilliant idea imho. Thank you :-)